# OrientDB SQL: How to find vertices and create edges between them?

Tags: sql, graph, graph-databases, orientdb

On my database I run the following query:

```
SELECT @rid AS module_rid, out('USES').out('BELONGS_TO').@rid AS project_rid FROM MODULES LIMIT 10
```

And I received the following response:

```
module_rid | project_rid
-----------|----------------
#12:0      | []
#12:1      | []
#12:2      | []
#12:3      |        
#11:48677  | #11:48677 #11:48677 #11:48677 #11:48677 #11:48677 ..More(49)
#12:4      |        
#11:48677  | #11:48677 #11:48677 #11:48677 #11:48677 #11:48677 ..More(49)
#12:5      |        
#11:2526   | #11:2526 #11:2526 #11:47148 #11:47148 #11:25338 ..More(30)
#12:6      | []
```

How can I create edges (e.g. RELIES_ON) between modules and the projects they rely on (they use at least one module of the project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

Define function `createEdges` with three parameters: `createEdges(from, to, type)`

```
// Check whether "from" is invalid or empty
if (from instanceof java.util.Collection) {
  if (from.isEmpty()) {
    return [];
  } else {
    var it = from.iterator();
    var obj = it.next();
    if (!(obj instanceof com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId)) {
      throw "Bad Input: createdEdges() only accepts ORecordIds or Collections of ORecordIds";
    }
  } 
} else if (!(from instanceof com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId)) {
  throw "Bad Input: createdEdges() only accepts ORecordIds or Collections of ORecordIds";
}

// Check whether "to" is invalid or empty
if (to instanceof java.util.Collection) {
  if (to.isEmpty()) {
    return [];
  } else {
    var it = to.iterator();
    var obj = it.next();
    if (!(obj instanceof com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId)) {
      throw "Bad Input: createdEdges() only accepts ORecordIds or Collections of ORecordIds";
    }
  } 
} else if (!(to instanceof com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId)) {
  throw "Bad Input: createdEdges() only accepts ORecordIds or Collections of ORecordIds";
}

var g = orient.getGraph();
var cmd = "CREATE EDGE " + type + " FROM " + from + " TO " + to;

return g.command("sql", cmd);
```

Define function `uniq` with one parameter: `uniq(collection)`

```
if (collection instanceof java.util.Collection) {
  if (collection.isEmpty()) {
    return collection
  } else {
    return new java.util.HashSet(collection)
  }
} else {
  throw "Bad Input: uniq() only accepts Java collections as input"
}
```

Now I can run the following SQL command:

```
SELECT createEdges(src, dst, 'RELIES_ON') FROM
(SELECT @rid AS src, uniq(out('USES').out('BELONGS_TO').@rid) AS dst FROM Modules)
```

This will create unique edges between the modules and the projects they rely on, and it is pretty fast.

*Credits go to @vitorenesduarte who provided the initial response and the main inspiration...*

Answer (score 2):

```
create class Module extends V
create class Project extends V

create class Uses extends E
create class ReliesOn extends E


create vertex Module set name = 'm1'
create vertex Module set name = 'm2'
create vertex Module set name = 'm3'

create vertex Project set name = 'p1'
create vertex Project set name = 'p2'
create vertex Project set name = 'p3'


create edge Uses from (select from Module where name = 'm2') to (select from Project where name = 'p1')
create edge Uses from (select from Module where name = 'm3') to (select from Project where name = 'p2')
create edge Uses from (select from Module where name = 'm3') to (select from Project where name = 'p3')
```

I understand the situation above is a little different from what you have, but I believe it will be enough to understand a possible solution to your problem.

You can define a function **createEdges** e.g., like this:

```
var gdb = orient.getGraph();

if(to.size() != 0){
    var command = "create edge ReliesOn from " + from + " to " + to;
    gdb.command("sql", command);
}
return;
```

[image]

And now the following query will find the vertices whilst creating the edges:

```
select from (
    select @rid as module_rid, out('Uses').@rid as project_rid from Module
)
let $ce = createEdges(module_rid, project_rid)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you want to assure that "to" does not contains duplicates, you can:

```
select from (
    select @rid as module_rid, $aux[0].set.@rid as project_rid from Module
    let $aux = ( select set(out('Uses')) from $current )
) 
let $ce = createEdges(module_rid, project_rid)
```

Comment: Great! I will check it tonight.

Comment: @retrography how did it go?

Comment: The issue is that the list of rids that I get in "to" contains many duplicates and I can't figure out how to make this list unique. I tried to treat "to" as an array so that I can remove the duplicate values out of it, but it seems like the variable is not recognized as  an array by the interpreter. Any idea what the nature of this collection is?

Comment: This is a great hack, but given that I have two degrees of separation between the source and the target, I need two levels of select nesting, and this slows down the operation to death (15 million iterations involved). It must be still fine, because this is a one-time operation, but isn't there any way to get the rids as a set rather than as a list?

Comment: Can't you `let $aux = ( select set(out('Uses').out('ThatOtherLevel')) from $current )`?

Comment: @vitorensduarte I actually can. But still very slow. Look at what I finally did below (or above, I don't know).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. What do you mean?
And about your solution, can't you remove `where size(out('USES').out('BELONGS_TO').@rid) > 0)` and let __createEdges__ function deal with the size? You're traversing twice with no need right?

Comment: `createEdges` already deals with it (in the updated version). You are right, that `where` clause is superfluous, I'll remove it. 

What I mean is this: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-unwind.html . I don't know of any means of achieving that in OrientDB.